# sort results in mongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb

I wrote some code in C# that brings 1000 documents from a collection, and I need to get these documents sorted from the newest to the oldest one. I know that a question like that was answered before, but I can't find one that fit my code. This is the code:

```
 DateTime dtLastDay = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
            var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MongoAddress"];
            var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
            var server = client.GetServer();
            var database = server.GetDatabase("Gnip");
            var collection = database.GetCollection<DOC>("GnipUL");
            collection.EnsureIndex(new IndexKeysBuilder().Ascending("Link"));                
            var query3 = Query.And(
            Query<DOC>.EQ(e1 => e1.Type, iType),
            Query<DOC>.GT (e1 => e1.dtPublish   , dtLastDay )                
          );

            //IMongoSortBy sort=Query<DOC>.EQ (e1 => e1.dtPublish ,-1);
            var search = collection.Find(query3).SetLimit(1000);

public class DOC
    {
        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
        public int Type { get; set; }
        public int taken { get; set; }
        public string Link { get; set; }
        public DateTime dtPublish { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Writer { get; set; }
        public string Identity { get; set; }
        public string Site { get; set; }
        public string SiteLink { get; set; }
    }
```

I know that I need to add to the line  `var search = collection.Find(query3).SetLimit(1000);`, .SetSort(), but I don't know what to write there, so it will be ordered by dtPublish.

Thanks in advance,
chen.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `SetSortOrder` as:

```
var search = collection.Find(query3)
    .SetSortOrder(SortBy.Descending("dtPublish"))
    .SetLimit(1000);
```

or more strongly typed:

```
var search = collection.Find(query3)
    .SetSortOrder(SortBy<DOC>.Descending(d => d.dtPublish))
    .SetLimit(1000);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but their is a problems: first you have to write it like that: `var search = collection.Find(query3).SetLimit (1000) .OrderByDescending(d => d.dtPublish);`. Second, the ordering is not working when you put the "Limit" option (without it work well).

Comment: @user2268845 Sorry I was mixing query styles and you're right, what I provided before wouldn't work.  See my updated answer.